# Migrating curity idsvr from log4j2 to logback

Tags: curity

Curity is currently using *log4j2* as the default logger. **Is there a way to change it to *logback*.**?

Currently I have build a custom Docker image doing the following steps. (base image used `curity.azurecr.io/curity/idsvr:6.7.2` )

1. Replaced the *log4j2.xml* file with a *logback.xml* file with logback configuration in the path `/opt/idsvr/etc/`
2. Removed existing *log4j* jar files in the path `/opt/idsvr/lib` and replaced with *logback* jar files downloaded from https://logback.qos.ch/download.html

After doing above steps I launched the custom image as a container. But I got the following error messages.

```
your customer that you accept the terms of the Curity License Agreement.

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
idsvr was installed into /opt/idsvr. You can begin using it by starting /opt/idsvr/bin/idsvr
openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.52+14-SA (build 11.0.13+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.52+14-SA (build 11.0.13+8-LTS, mixed mode)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/core/impl/LogEventFactory
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at se.curity.identityserver.app.LogInitializer.initializeLoggers(LogInitializer.java:54)
    at se.curity.identityserver.app.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:118)
    at se.curity.identityserver.app.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:100)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.LogEventFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
```

Any help would be kindy appreciated. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, replacing Log4j with Logback is not supported. The [use of Log4j](https://developer.curity.io/docs/latest/system-admin-guide/logging/index.html) runs very deep in the product, and cannot be replaced by users. I'd recommend asking another questions about the issue that led you to want to replace the ❤️ of the logging subsystem. Perhaps that has a solution that doesn't require heart surgery.